# Resharper compatibility issue with ASP.NET core 1.0

Tags: c#, razor, resharper

Today I installed .NET Core framework and when I created a new ASP.NET Core project I noticed that Resharper marks almost all razor keywords such "Html", "Section" and "ViewData" as "cannot resolve symbol" and all the quick actions regarding when editing those keywords are unavailable. Also it marks almost all html tags that come with ASP.NET as cannot resolve as well. I am sure that bug comes from Resharper since disabling resharper fixes it.
I tried:

- Reinstalling Resharper with latest version.
- Stopping and then resuming Resharper in Tools > Option
- Reinstalling .NET Core altogether (for some other reason, but problem still exist)

I really like Resharper and since I work on other projects side by side ASP.NET project, I really rather not disable Resharper entirely and if you can't think of any solution for this compatibility problem, I would be thankful if you can tell me how to disable Resharper on cshtml files only, cuz all these red keywords are really annoying.

**Update:** I found out how to disable inspection on cshtml files according to 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html

Comment: JetBrains hasn't yet announce full support for .NET Core 1.0. It is very likely that you need to upgrade to their next major release.

Comment: I'd like to see a bug report for this somewhere- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP

Comment: It looks like I might have just found the bug and it looks like it may have been fixed in EAP 1 - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-458852#u=1463700018013

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After downloading EAP 19 from the following link, I no longer have this problem.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+2016.2+EAP

Here's the bug report that was used to fix this
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-458852#u=1463700018013

Comment: thanks for the answer, my problem did get solved but i feel like resharper is still not fully compatible with .net core. i still sometimes see the same "cannot resolve symbol" error when i open new .cshtml files and i have to rebuild or close and reopen the file so the errors go away.

Comment: If you're using the just released final version of 2016.2 and you're still seeing these issues, please [file an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RSRP&clearDraft=true&c=).